# Web Component can't find variable `require`

Tags: javascript, static-resources, lightning-web-components

I am trying to use the `json2csv` javascript package in my Salesforce Web Component, but I get the error: `can't find variable 'require'`.

I've uploaded the json2csv package as a static resource and am loading it via:

```
import JSON2CSV from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/JSON2CSV';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    /**
     * Variables
     */

    json2csvInitialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.json2csvInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.json2csvInitialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, JSON2CSV)
        ])
        .then(() => {
            var csvString = this.testJson2Csv(json);
            console.log(csvString);
        })
    }

    testJson2Csv() {
        const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv').Parser;
        const fields = ['carModel', 'price', 'items.name', 'items.color', 'items.items.position', 'items.items.color'];
        const myCars = [
            {
              "carModel": "BMW",
              "price": 15000,
              "items": [
                {
                  "name": "airbag",
                  "color": "white"
                }, {
                  "name": "dashboard",
                  "color": "black"
                }
              ]
            }, {
              "carModel": "Porsche",
              "price": 30000,
              "items": [
                {
                  "name": "airbag",
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "position": "left",
                      "color": "white"
                    }, {
                      "position": "right",
                      "color": "gray"
                    }
                  ]
                }, {
                  "name": "dashboard",
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "position": "left",
                      "color": "gray"
                    }, {
                      "position": "right",
                      "color": "black"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
        ];
        const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields, unwind: ['items', 'items.items'], unwindBlank: true });
        const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);
        return csv;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? How else am I suppose to use the parser?

Comment: You don't seem to be loading the JS from the resource. `loadScript(this, JSON2CSV)` -- isn't this missing the path for the JS within your static resource?

Comment: You'll need to import [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/) in order for this library to work.

Comment: @JayantDas I don't believe so since it's just the resource file. The file is not contained in a zip or anything.

Comment: @sfdcfox do you know if I have to upload my own static resource for that, or is `requirejs` default in the salesforce environment?

Comment: @BlondeSwan Yes, you'd need to import requirejs. Alternatively, if you're trying to use the NPM, you can try using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bundle require/json2csv/etc all in a single resource.

Comment: I see, I had somehow made the assumption that it was a zip file. But I think you got your answer, you will need to make sure the required libraries are available in salesforce as static resources before you can use it in the component.

Comment: @sfdcfox so I downloaded the require.js file from https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js and zipped it up with my resource and uploaded to salesforce. The resource loads fine, but it still doesn't know what `require` is...

Comment: by the resource loads fine, I mean that I don't get an error during the loading of the resource. I get the error when I try to use require

Comment: @BlondeSwan You'd probably have better luck using browserify. It looks like json2csv is rather complicated (3 dependencies, 17 dev dependencies). Generally speaking, npm modules are not browser-friendly by default.

Comment: so the `cannot find variable 'require'` error could be an error with getting `json3csv`, not necessarily the actual require function?

Comment: I will try Browserify, but do you have any good tutorials on how to use it to bundle together resources?

Comment: turns out you don't need `Require`. you just need to replace `const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv');` to `const Json2csvParser = json2csv.Parser; `

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you just need to replace

```
const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv').Parser;
```

with

```
const Json2csvParser = json2csv.Parser;
```